# Proving Expectation law for $E[\max{X,Y}]$

Tags: probability, expected-value

Prove:
$$E[\max{X,Y}] = E[X] + E[Y] - E[\min{X,Y}]$$ where $X, Y$ are random variables.

Attempt:
$\max{X,Y}= X,$ $X$ greater than or equal to $Y$
$Y, X$ less than or equal to $Y$

$\min{X,Y}= Y,$ $X$ greater than or equal to $Y$
$X$, $X$ less than or equal to $Y$

Do I start with using the definition of Expectation?:
$$E[X] = \sum_i (i\cdot \operatorname{Pr}(X=i))$$

Comment: $\min(a,b)+\max(a,b)=a+b$ for any $a,b$.

Answer (score 4):

It can easily be shown that for $a,b\in\mathbb R$,
$$
\min\{a,b\} + \max\{a,b\} = a+b.
$$
If $\mathbb E[|X|]<\infty$ and $\mathbb E[|Y|]<\infty$ then
$$
\mathbb E[\max\{X,Y\}] \leqslant \mathbb E[|X|] + \mathbb E[|Y|]<\infty
$$
and similarly we see that $\min\{X,Y\}$ has finite expectation. Since
$$
\min\{X,Y\} + \max\{X,Y\} = X+Y
$$
with probability one, taking expectations yields
$$
\mathbb E[\min\{X,Y\} + \max\{X,Y\}] = \mathbb E[X+Y],
$$
from which we conclude.

Comment: Thank you. This is my first time posting on stack exchange. What should I do once I got the help? Do I press the up button on your reply?

Comment: @TuanVo You can upvote and/or accept the answer if you found it helpful, yes.